# Vagrant Losing Sessions with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have been developing a laravel application on vagrant for few weeks now. And very frequently I am running into an issue when the session variables are completely dropped. It seems to be happening every time I do an rsync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is being caused because unlike the default php session laravel have the session information configured to save in app/storage/sessions. The location where this saves can be changed in the sessions.php config file. However I don't recommend changing the location that the sessions save to at least not on vagrant as you will run into a few other permission issues.

Simply adding these lines to your Vagrantfile will fix the issue. Note the path may be different as I use a public folder to house all application files.

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./public", "/vagrant", type: "rsync",
rsync__exclude: "/api/*/app/storage/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check owner&group in vagrant configuration file

```
config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/vagrant/", id: "vagrant-root" ,  type: "nfs" , :owner => 'www-data', :group => 'www-data'
```